# Xamarin iOS custom keyboard does not work properly

Tags: ios, xamarin, custom-keyboard

I am developing a keyboard extension for my application and have some issues with it. I need transfer some small amount of data from main application to keyboard. For this purpose I write values to NSUserDefaults, which are shared between app and extension. I also added observers to some keys in user defaults to track when values change and take appropriate actions. 
It must work in that sequence: keyboard writes something to user defaults -> observer fires in application -> application writes response -> observer fires in keyboard. They write values for different keys.
Here is code for registering observers in keyboard:

```
    void RegisterObservers()
    {
        byte[] buff = new byte[4];
        rng.GetNonZeroBytes(buff);
        appRunToken = (IntPtr)buff[0];
        accountsToken = (IntPtr)buff[1];
        passwordToken = (IntPtr)buff[2];
        otpToken = (IntPtr)buff[3];

        plist.AddObserver(this, (NSString)"AppRun",
                              NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Old | NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New,
                              appRunToken);
        plist.AddObserver(this, (NSString)"Accounts",
                              NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Old | NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New,
                              accountsToken);
        plist.AddObserver(this, (NSString)"CurrentPassword",
                              NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Old | NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New,
                              passwordToken);
        plist.AddObserver(this, (NSString)"CurrentOTP",
                              NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Old | NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New,
                              passwordToken);
    }
```

And this method is called when one of the observers fires:

```
// NSUserDefaults observer
    public override void ObserveValue(NSString keyPath, NSObject ofObject, NSDictionary change, IntPtr context)
    {
        try
        {
            if (context == appRunToken)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(">>>Observer fired: appRunToken");
                // some strange workaround to get bool from change dictionary
                if (((NSNumber)change.ValueForKey((NSString)"new")).Equals(new NSNumber(0)))
                    AppRunChangedEvent?.Invoke(new AppRunChangedEventArgs(false));
                else
                    AppRunChangedEvent?.Invoke(new AppRunChangedEventArgs(true));
            }
            else if (context == accountsToken)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(">>>Observer fired: accountsToken");
            }
            else if (context == passwordToken)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(">>>Observer fired: passwordToken");
                PasswordChangedEvent.Invoke(new PasswordChangedEventArgs(plist.StringForKey("someRandomStringGeneratedAutomatically")));
                plist.SetString("", "someRandomStringGeneratedAutomatically");
            } 
            else if (context == otpToken) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(">>>Observer fired: otp token");
                OTPChangedEvent.Invoke(new OTPChangedEventArgs(plist.StringForKey("CurrentOtp")));
                plist.SetString("", "CurrentOtp");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The same approach is used in main application.
The problem is that just after writing info to user defaults keyboard freezes. After I perform gesture to hide keyboard it hides with tugging and after opening it again I have this output in console multiple times:

```
Full thread dump:

"<unnamed thread>"
"<unnamed thread>"
"Finalizer"
"<unnamed thread>"
"Debugger agent"
```

Then keyboard switches to the previous one.

Sometimes UI just freezes without any output and sometimes observers don`t fire at all.

Then I've tried to get rid of observers in keyboard and read values from NSUserDefaults after delay using Task.Delay(200). Looks like 200 is enough for application to react to NSUserDefaults value change and write response. I have the same behavior like before except console message. Now it is something like

```
Full thread dump:

"Debugger agent"
"<unnamed thread>"
"Finalizer"
"<unnamed thread>"
"Threadpool worker"
"<unnamed thread>"
"Timer-Scheduler" at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne_internal (intptr,int) <0x00007>
at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative (System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle,uint,bool,bool) [0x0000a] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/WaitHandle.cs:104
at System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne (System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle,long,bool,bool) [0x00014] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/waithandle.cs:250
at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne (long,bool) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/waithandle.cs:239
at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne (int,bool) [0x00019] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/waithandle.cs:206
at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne (int) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/waithandle.cs:227
at System.Threading.Timer/Scheduler.SchedulerThread () [0x0020b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/Timer.cs:395
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (object) [0x00014] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:68
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00071] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:957
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:904
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object) [0x0002b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:893
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:105
at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_dynamic (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0001e] in <d680a8bf3a2a4c8dbbfde665ba81f6f2>:0

"<unnamed thread>"
"<threadpool thread>"
```

And sometimes everything works fine.
What`s wrong with keyboard and NSUserDefauts? Please, help me figure this out

**UPDATE**.
I've tried to replace NSUserDefaults observers with CFNotificationCenter.Darwin observers and got the same behavior. What a hell is wrong with observers in Xamarin keyboard? When I remove them everything works fine. Looks like I have to write my application in Swift

Comment: Can you post some code about how are you working with it?

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT yes, I added some code

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT have any ideas about this problem? I will really appreciate any help or advices.

Comment: @Mike.P were you able to solve this? I have run in a similar issue